# How to find the index of textbox on keyup event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement filtering the table rows using jquery. I have markup like http://jsfiddle.net/NKNmW/1/

When ever i click on the filter button i am showing the textboxes. Now i want to know in which textbox i am typing,i.e., index of the textbox. For this I written one keyup event which calls below function.

```
   var filterQuery = function (thisElement) {
           console.log(thisElement.index());
    };
$(document).on('keyup', '.filterBox', function () { filterQuery($(this)); });
```

But I am unable to get the index of the typing text box. Am I using `index()` function in wrong way? Can any one tell where the mistake was??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `class` as the parameter:

```
thisElement.index(".filterBox")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKNmW/2/